# Write PHP to same XML document, rather than create one for each iteration

Tags: php, xml, fopen, fwrite

I'm writing some PHP code that reads an XML template and replaces some values within the template with data from an array in PHP. Currently when the code is executed it will output a file for each iteration of the loop, each which has the correct values replaced.

The problem that I am facing is trying to get each output on to the same XML document, rather than one each. Below is the code as of present;

```
<?

$filename = 'MYDRIVE\XML_TEMPLATE2.xml';
$contents = file_get_contents($filename); 

$emaillist = array(array('fname'            => 'Brad',
                         'lname'            => 'BoBo',
                         'recipient'        => 'bbobo@gmail.com'),  

                   array('fname'            => 'Josh',
                         'lname'            => 'Jojo',
                         'recipient'        => 'jjojo@gmail.com'),

                   array('fname'            => 'Sam',
                         'lname'            => 'Soso',
                         'recipient'        => 'ssoso@gmail.com'),

                   array('fname'            => 'Dave',
                         'lname'            => 'Dojo',
                         'recipient'        => 'ddojo@hotmail.com'));

foreach ($emaillist as &$person) 
{

    $fname      = $person['fname'];
    $lname      = $person['lname'];
    $recipient  = $person['recipient'];
    $todaysdate = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 

    $find       = array("[[firstname]]",
                        "[[lastname]]",
                        "[[recipient]]",
                        "[[todaysdate]]");

    $replace    = array($fname,
                        $lname,
                        $recipient,
                        $todaysdate);

    $new        = str_replace($find,
                              $replace,
                              $contents);

    // This will open/ create the file if non-existent.

    $handle      = fopen("MYDRIVE/tempname.xml", "w+");

    $filename    = 'MYDRIVE/tempname.xml';
    $filecontent = $new;

    if (is_writable($filename)) 
    { 
        print "<b>Data added to file:</b>";
        print "<br>";
        print "<br>";

        if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) 
        {
             print "Cannot open file ($filename)";
             exit;
        }

        // Adds $filecontent to file.

        if (fwrite($handle, $filecontent) === FALSE) 
        {
            print "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
            exit;
        }

        print "Success! <br><br> ($filecontent) <br><br> was added to ($filename)";

        fclose($handle);

    } 
    else 
    {
        print "<b>Error:</b>";
        print "The file $filename is not writable";
        exit();
    }

    // Generate file name for use.

    $filenamegen = date("d_h_i_s") . "_" . $person['recipient'];

    if (rename ("MYDRIVE/tempname.xml", "MYDRIVE/" . $filenamegen . ".xml"))
    { 
        print "File successfully saved as : $filenamegen";
        print "<br><br>";
    }
    else
    {
        print "Error renaming file.";
        exit();
    }

print "</div>";

}

?>
```

When The above code is executed, 4 XML documents are created, with the variables correctly replaced for each record of data.

The problem that I am facing is trying to get all of the data in to a single XML file. If anyone could give any advice regarding this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks as always,

Comment: Append (`.=`) your `$new` to `$filecontent` instead of setting it (`=`) and do the `fwrite` after the `foreach`-loop

Answer (score 1):

There are several thinks i believe that can be done better , firstly as Andreas said , you're re assigning the var $new at every loop , so remember a the concat operator dot :

```
$new .= str_replace($find,$replace,$contents);
```

and at the end of the loop you will got concatenated all loops iteration on $new .

I suggest you to open document as this :

```
<?php
```

Instead of this :

```
<?
```

By this way php will be able to work with XML .

And i suggest to use the specific library to deal with XML instead of the way you're doing.

[simpleXml PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

It's better idea to construct your xml and parse / save intead of working it with disk ... you will face a lot of troubles in future with special chars , charsets ..etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
<?php

$filename = 'MYDRIVE\XML_TEMPLATE2.xml';
$contents = file_get_contents($filename); 

$emaillist = array(array('fname'            => 'Brad',
                         'lname'            => 'BoBo',
                         'recipient'        => 'bbobo@gmail.com'),  

                   array('fname'            => 'Josh',
                         'lname'            => 'Jojo',
                         'recipient'        => 'jjojo@gmail.com'),

                   array('fname'            => 'Sam',
                         'lname'            => 'Soso',
                         'recipient'        => 'ssoso@gmail.com'),

                   array('fname'            => 'Dave',
                         'lname'            => 'Dojo',
                         'recipient'        => 'ddojo@hotmail.com'));

// This will open/ create the file if non-existent.

$handle      = fopen("MYDRIVE/tempname.xml", "w+");
$filename    = 'MYDRIVE/tempname.xml';
$filecontent = '';
foreach ($emaillist as &$person) 
{

    $fname      = $person['fname'];
    $lname      = $person['lname'];
    $recipient  = $person['recipient'];
    $todaysdate = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 

    $find       = array("[[firstname]]",
                        "[[lastname]]",
                        "[[recipient]]",
                        "[[todaysdate]]");

    $replace    = array($fname,
                        $lname,
                        $recipient,
                        $todaysdate);

    $new        = str_replace($find,
                              $replace,
                              $contents);

    $filecontent .= $new;
}
if (is_writable($filename)) 
{ 
    print "<b>Data added to file:</b>";
    print "<br>";
    print "<br>";

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) 
    {
         print "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }

    // Adds $filecontent to file.

    if (fwrite($handle, $filecontent) === FALSE) 
    {
        print "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }

    print "Success! <br><br> ($filecontent) <br><br> was added to ($filename)";

    fclose($handle);

} 
else 
{
    print "<b>Error:</b>";
    print "The file $filename is not writable";
    exit();
}

// Generate file name for use.

$filenamegen = date("d_h_i_s");

if (rename ("MYDRIVE/tempname.xml", "MYDRIVE/" . $filenamegen . ".xml"))
{ 
    print "File successfully saved as : $filenamegen";
    print "<br><br>";
}
else
{
    print "Error renaming file.";
    exit();
}

print "</div>";
```

If you have the XML header in your `XML_TEMPLATE2.xml`, you should remove it there and instead add it to `$filecontent` **before** the `foreach`-loop. Same for the root-node - open it **before** the `foreach` and close it after the `foreach`.

Comment: Hi, this gave only one xml file with only the first result

Comment: Just checked it that moment - it works as expected. Check, if you have defined `$filecontent = ''` **before** the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Hi, yeah and still no luck with this!

Comment: Can you show your `XML_TEMPLATE2` and the output you get?